# Installing Kinect with OpenNI on Windows8

Tags: windows-8, kinect

I'm following these instructions 
http://www.kinecthacks.com/guides/install-kinect-on-your-pc-and-start-developing-your-programs-disclaimer/

but so far have had no luck. I'm getting an error when installing the Sensor KinectMod saying I need OpenNI 1.2.0.4 or greater(even though I have the latest OpenNI2 installed) and also in my device manager I don't see any PrimeSense devices listed after plugging in my Kinect.

I'm also confused by what the ' OpenNI Compliant HARDWARE Binaries' are and where I should download them.

Can anyone point me to an up to date tutorial for installing OpenNI with a Xbox Kinect device on Windows8?

Comment: The likely problem is your using a XBOX 360 Kinect instead one designed for Windows.  Seems like you will have to contact OpenNI's authors to address the bug in their software.

Comment: I needed to install Kinect for Windows first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Openni2, it's the latest version which directly supports Windows SDK (even for Xbox Kinect).

- Uninstall everything like drivers, Openni2, Nite2
- Install Kinect SDK 1.6
- Reinstall only Openni2 and Nite